# mysql - finding string from array

Tags: mysql, arrays, sql-like

Database table:

```
id| p1 | p2 | notes
1 | 1  | a  | cat, mouse, dog
2 | 1  | a  | cat, horse, dog
```

I now need to run a query that selects the row where "notes" does not contain a string defined in the $exclusions array. I have tried the LIKE '%mouse%' operator, but that gave an error.

```
$exclusions = array ("mouse");
if($row['p1'] == 1 && $row['p2'] == "a" && $row['notes'] not like '%mouse%') {...}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Without a little more to refer to, it's hard to identify what the syntax problem might be...for example I don't see the WHERE...is there and AND missing, or an OR?  "NOT LIKE '%mouse%' is correct syntax, so your usage of it within the rest of the SQL statement must be wrong.

Comment: My guess is the OP wants the logic done in the PHP code. So the SQL statement is most likely a "select * from table"; it is unclear if they want the solution via the sql command or the php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are doing the logic in a mix of PHP code and sql. To do it in php, you can do

```
!strstr($row['notes'], 'mouse')
```

That says "If there is no occurrence of "mouse" in $row['notes']"

The ! will make it return true if there is no occurrence.

Comment: thanks - this works!  how do i modify this if there are more than one string to be excluded?

Comment: Sorry, I needed to delete that last comment due to an error. It is best to write out the logic on paper for how you want the code to behave, so you don't get mixed up in NOTs, ANDs, and ORs.

For example, you dont want any result that has "mouse" or "dog" would look like:

!strstr($row['notes'], 'mouse') || !strstr($row['notes'], 'dog')
Literally meaning: "No occurrence of mouse OR no occurrence of dog".... You can also write the code without the NOT operand-- "strstr($row['notes'], 'mouse')" - which means, "if(Notes contains mouse) ... "

Comment: actually - the || operand appears not to be working, while stacking && one after the other does

Answer (score 0):

```
if($row['p1'] == 1 && $row['p2'] == "a" && $row['notes'] not like '%mouse%') {...}
```

This is not MySQL syntax. It looks like PHP, and in PHP you can not use `LIKE`. Try a string comparison operator like `strstr`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

**Mysql Style**

A query to get all rows without mouse could be this:

```
 SELECT * FROM `tablename` 
 WHERE `notes` NOT LIKE '%mouse%';
```

Or to get the exclusions from a php array:

```php
 $condition = "WHERE ";
 $first = true;
 foreach($exclusions as $ex) {
      if(!$first) $condition .= " AND "; // or use OR
      $condition .= "`notes` NOT LIKE \"%$ex%\"";
      $first = false;
 }

 $complete_query = "SELECT * FROM `tablename` $condition;";
```